# Среда Classic больше не поддерживается

Tags: xcode

Всем привет. Я создал приложение для *Mac OS X* (*xcode 5, MAc OS X 10.9*) и передал файл с расширением `app` этого проекта другому человеку. А он его запустить на своем компе не может. Говорит ошибка: не удается запустить приложение т.к. среда *Classic* больше не поддерживается. У него *Mac OS X 10.8.5*

Ничего не могу понять. Как запустить и что за среда *Classic*?

Comment: [Статья в википедии][1]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Environment